# Warning: Copy is an invalid command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'd like to transfer data from s3 to a table in redshift postgres.

It is stored as a csv in my bucket on s3.

I set up amazon CLI and already ran `configure` and added my credentials and gave myself an IAM user with access to the s3 bucket and the redshift postgres instance.

I ran the command `aws copy tmp3 from s3://[mybucket]/[mycsv].csv`

But I got back the error `aws: error: argument command: Invalid choice, valid choices are` and copy is not on the list of vlaid commands that they offer.

Comment: You seem to be confusing the S3 copy command (which copies files between locations in S3), and the Redshift copy command (which copies data from S3 into Redshift).

Comment: I'm trying to replicate this command https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_loading-tables-from-s3.html

Comment: Do I execute this command from the aws command line interface?

Comment: No, you execute that from the Redshift database.

Answer (score 0):

Copy is not a supported argument, what you're looking for is `cp`. Have a look at the [AWS CLI Documentation for S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html).

What you're looking for is probably this:

> aws s3 cp s3://[mybucket]/[mycsv].csv tmp3